# How to fix "Identifier 'length' is not defined" error appearing in VS Code, but code works as expected

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I'm displaying a div if an array in my FormGroup has more than 1 item.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
*ngIf="employeeForm.get('skills').length>1
```

The code is working as expected (the div is only displayed if the array length is greater than one).

But in VS Code, I'm getting a red-line under the above code.
Here is the error I get:

> Identifier 'length' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain
>   such a memberAngular

Can someone please tell me what I need to do so that this red line is removed?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because by default a `form.get('key')` returns an AbstractControl type, which doesn't have a `length` property. You need to explicitly tell that the returned control is a FormGroup, a FormControl, a FormArray, etc (Code Editors see this return type and try to give you warnings if you are trying to access any property which doesn't exist in the return type).

For you, make a getter like:

```
get skills() {
    return this.emplyeeForm.get('skills') as FormArray
}
```

and your view be like:

```
<div *ngIf="skills.length>1"> ... </div>
```

This is just for users readability and editor's intellisence. If the returned control is a FormArray then during runtime it will have a length property in it and your your code will run without errors.

Answer (score 1):

define your own getter so you can define what attributes it does and doesn't have.

```
public get skills(): any[] // define your type here or keep this.
{
    return this.emplyeeForm.controls['skills']. value;
}

*ngIf="skills.length"
```

Comment: The issue seems to be more of VS code understanding the type, the control may be a FormArray

Comment: my bad oopsssss